# Unable to access property using MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to access the property

```
public string gridHTML { get; set; }
```

that I have defined in my controller. I am trying to access this property using the JavaScript, MVC3 Razor
like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var str = @Model.gridHTML ;
}
```

but i am getting the error that the above variable is not defined. Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you strongly typed your view that is passed the model to your view?

Comment: You said you defined the property on your controller. Surely you mean that you defined it on the model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have passed the model correctly then the following should work, unless the razor syntax is not residing inside a separate `js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var str = '@:Model.gridHTML';
   console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: i got the exception while trying your code, does not contain a definition for 'gridHTML' and no extension method 'gridHTML' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

Talha,

In the comments to 3nigma's question, you make an interesting note:

```
does not contain a definition for 'gridHTML' and no extension method 'gridHTML' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
```

are you certain that you are passing a single object to your view?? It sounds to me as tho you are using an ienumerable list that contains your class. Perhaps a paste of both the class and the razor view header section would tease your question out a little further.